# Windows 10 1511 Explorer Freezing

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

I updated my Windows 10 installation to 1511. Shortly after, I experienced the following for the first time:

First, a popup alert from the Notification Center will appear and not disappear. On mouser over the X to close it will not appear. Sometimes, you can click on the Notification Center Icon in the taskbar, and the notification will go away. But the next thing is that the Notification Center will not slide out, whatever happens.

A few minutes after this happens, the task bar will jam up completely, and the start menu will not open (not by the button or the key). Alt+Tab will not work, or Win+Tab, so as soon as you've minimized a window you have "lost" it.

The only way to fix this is to restart `explorer.exe` but I'm getting tired of doing it almost every two hours.

I know it's not my computer - as in lack of processing power, because my laptop has a quad core i7, and 16gb of ram, and I can be happily running Photoshop and Illustrator when this happens - CPU around 30% and RAM 60%. I can also only have a couple of tabs in Chrome open and it happens.

Is there a fix? I'm 90% sure I'm fully up to date with the updates.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @mxmissile I believe when I updated from 1511 it fixed itself. Can't quite recall. You could try swapping over to an insider build and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the following keys with **REGEDIT** or your favorite registry tool.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
```

Try deleting both the **BagMRU** and **Bags** keys.

Threshold 2 in-place upgrades. I have seen this issue with several of our version 1511 build 10586 virtual machines that were upgraded in-place. For some reason the folder view settings seem to be pointing to old incorrect settings or were otherwise corrupted during the migration.

Additional details regarding **BagMRU** and **Bags** are available [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17707-folder-view-settings-reset-default-windows-10-a.html).